# Inclination angle with respect to a plane

Tags: geometry, angle

I have performed some molecular dynamics simulation and outcome gives position of each atom in Cartesian coordinate system. The outcome looking like this, [image]

where the yellow atoms some sort of liquid so they move around and red and blue atoms stick together and act as a solid body. Both solid bodies half submerged inside liquid and it can rotate around itself. My aim is to find the approximate angle of inclination that any solid body makes with respect to liquid plane. The angle can vary from 0 to 90 degree. How can I extract the angle from the position of all atoms?

Comment: Do the liquid surface really form a plane or there are some macroscopic distortions (like waves)? Is the direction of gravitational force known?

Comment: Not sure I completely understand your situation, but perhaps looking into principal moments of inertia might be a first step:  https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/32921/whats-the-right-way-to-calculate-the-principal-moment-of-inertia could be useful in this regards.  I hope this helps.

Comment: @user they have some distortion but at a large scale that is negligible..that's why an approximation will be fine. I am thinking some sort of vector perpendicular to center of the solid and measure angle with respect to that vector as I can consider the COM of solid body is at the plane.

Comment: @ad2004 sure, I will look into that.

Comment: The real problem here is finding the normal to the liquid surface. After this is done you can trivially compute the required angle for any solid body.

Comment: @user is it possible to calculate the orientation with respect to their own center of mass?

Comment: I would ask: "what is the reason for appearance of the surface in the calculation?" From your figure I would assume it is the gravitation. In this case the normal of the surface is simply collinear with the gravitational force.

Comment: @user thats somewhat different. the empty space you can see is another type of fluid and the interface created due to repulsion in between them.

Answer (score 0):

The solid direction can be found either by a PCA on the columns as pointed out by @ad2004 or by a regression to a straight line.

To find the surface normal I propose 2 options:

1. consider the surface to to be defined by a vector $N$ and a scalar $d$ such that the points $P$ that obey $N\cdot P+d=0$ are on the surface, and thus all the liquid points $L_i$ must obey $N\cdot L_i+d<0$. Find $N,d$ by optimizing a softened version of $\sum sign(N \cdot L_i +d)$.   $\,\,erf(x)$ or $\arctan(x)$ come to mind.

2. Find the boundary layer by looking for sharp changes in the density ( by convolving with  a Canny filter or something similar and then thresholding), then take the points that were determined to be on the boundary $B_i$ and do a regression to minimize $\sum(n \cdot B_i +1)^2$ and determine $N,d$ by normalizing $n$ so that $|N|=1$